# How to change the example values for api requests in Swagger UI?

Tags: api, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm making an API for a site and I'm using Swagger UI, I currently have a route for adding a favorite for a user the route is `"/users/{id}/favorites/"`, and the params in the spec are:

```
        "parameters":[
          {
            "in":"path",
            "name":"id",
            "description":"User's Id",
            "required":true,
            "schema":{
              "$ref":"#/definitions/User"
            }
          },
          {
            "in":"body",
            "name":"body",
            "description":"Enter user's id and video id for favorite",
            "required":true,
            "schema":{
              "$ref":"#/definitions/Favorite"
            }
          }
        ],
```

The definition for the favorites model in the spec looks like this:

```
"Favorite":{
  "type":"object",
  "properties":{
    "id":{
      "type":"integer",
      "format": "int64"
    },
    "userId":{
      "$ref":"#/definitions/User/properties/id"
    },
    "videoId":{
      "$ref":"#/definitions/Video/properties/id"
    }
  },
  "xml":{
    "name":"Flag"
  }
}
```

But currently when I go the `/api` route the example value being shown for the body param is

```
{
  "id": 0
}
```

on the docs it displays an almost correct request sample correctly and shows:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "userId": 0,
  "videoId": 0
}
```

How do I change the example value for the `/api` route to show

```
{
  "userId": 0,
  "videoId": 0
}
```

as an example and how do I remove the id param from the example on the doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it, not sure if this is the best way but I just changed the definition and made userId an int instead of a $ref and the same for videoId.